# How to avoid in a Mac app that an item of a NStableView is highlighted when empty?

Tags: macos, nstableview, highlight

I have a app for macOS where I use a view based NSTableView as a list of clickable items that start an action. Because in Cocoa there are not groups in tableView I separated all the items of a certain type with a blank item (which has three spaces as text).

How can get to not highlight the item with three space as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement delegate method

```
- (NSIndexSet *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView selectionIndexesForProposedSelection:(NSIndexSet *)proposedSelectionIndexes;
```

or

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)row;
```